# PHP STRING ISSUE IN DISPAYIND DATA

Tags: string

Write a program for the below mentioned question:

Create a string variable, str1 and assign it some value, say “abcd”

Find the number of times the letter ‘a’ occurs in str1 and print the count to console.

For example, if str1 = aba, the output should be 2

Note : You can take syntax help from w3schools.com

Tests:

1. Ask the candidate to assign str1=cat. Output should 1
2. Ask the candidate to type : mno. Output should be 0
3. Ask the candidate to type : aaabbbccc. Output should be 3

Comment: Did you just copy-paste some exercice from an online course ?  Where is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "cat";
echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

$string = "mno";
echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

$string = "aaabbbccc";
echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "aba"; 
echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

$string = "cat"; 
echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");
```

Hope this can be useful

Comment: thanks a lot its working $string = "cat"; echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

$string = "mno"; echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

$string = "aaabbbccc"; echo 'output is :- '.substr_count($string,"a");

Comment: @NaveenChaudhari if this is working for you then please accept answer by upvoting answer.